# Search according to the best field match in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

Searching for "foo bar" on the document below will score an accumulative result of `name*`, but I would like to get the score of the best matched field (i.e `name1` score).

```
{
  "name1": "foo bar",
  "name2": "foo",
  "name3": "bar"
}
```

Query for example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "match": {
              "name1": {
                "query": "foo bar"
              }
            }
          }, {
            "match": {
              "name2": {
                "query": "foo bar"
              }
            }
          }, {
            "match": {
              "name3": {
                "query": "foo bar"
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using Elasticsearch 2.4

Comment: Maybe want to share your query? :)

Comment: @ByronVoorbach edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) combines the score of all subqueries . From docs:

> The bool query takes a more-matches-is-better approach, so the score
>   from each matching must or should clause will be added together to
>   provide the final _score for each document.

For your case, you would like to use another joining query: [The dis_max query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html#query-dsl-dis-max-query)

> A query that generates the union of documents produced by its
>   subqueries, and that scores each document with the maximum score for
>   that document as produced by any subquery, plus a tie breaking
>   increment for any additional matching subqueries.

Example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name1": {
              "query": "foo bar"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name2": {
              "query": "foo bar"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name3": {
              "query": "foo bar"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Note, I wrote this on ES6, which doesn't have `filtered` query anymore, but I hope you get the gist :)

Hope this helps!